# display line chart in chartjs with multiple labels and multiple datasets from api

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm facing a problem with multiple datasets and multiple labels. each label array has it's own dataset so how am I suppose to plot the line chart in chartjs

This is how I'm trying to display my data with their labels on chart but only axis are being displayed not the line

```js
createChart() {
    this.renderChart({
          labels: date_list,
          type: Line,
          datasets: [{
                label: 'I',
                data: {
                  x: this.labels_i,
                  y: this.data_i,
                },
              }, {
                label: 'E',
                data: {
                  x: this.labels_e,
                  y: this.data_e,
                },
              },
```

Comment: Please provide us some code, show us what you already have tried :)

Comment: You can [edit] your question instead of adding code in comments

Comment: @barbsan ohk thanks.

Comment: @kalehmann can you help?